# IntelliJ IDEA: CSS class autocomplete in *.html.erb with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, sass, bootstrap-sass, intellij-13

I have IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 with Ruby plugin installed. My Rails project is properly set up to use the `bootstrap-sass` gem and works fine in the browser.

As per Rails convention I have a file (`app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss`) which `@imports "bootstrap"` on its first line and contains custom styles. Autocompletion works mostly fine within this file (ie Bootstrap variables and classes pop up on ctrl+space).

I'd like autocompletion of Bootstrap classes to be available when editing `*.html.erb` files too (or any html file for that matter). Is that possible?

ps In `*.html.erb` files, the only css classes available for autocompletion are just the ones directly defined in `custom.css.scss`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an [open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5879) for quite some time now. **Please upvote if you want this fixed.**

For now, and as a workaround, you can place the compiled `bootstrap.css` inside your project and the IDE should provide auto-completion from it. (props to Alexander Zolotov)

[Link to forum post](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5517807)